# Проблема с импортом переменных

Tags: python, файлы, переменные, импорт

Пишу бота для Telegramm.

Файл settings.py:

```
COOKIE = ''
bnc_vuid = ''
device_info = ''

headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.63 Safari/537.36',
    'clienttype': 'web',
    'cookie': COOKIE.encode('UTF-8'),
    'csrftoken': CSRFTOKEN,
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'bnc-uuid': bnc_vuid,
    'device-info' : device_info,
}
```

Объявление этих переменных происходит в другом файле, bot.py:

```
import binance1.settings
date = db.post_date_in_setting(message.from_user.id)

binance1.settings.CSRFTOKEN = date[0]
binance1.settings.COOKIE = date[1]
binance1.settings.device_info = date[2]
binance1.settings.bnc_vuid= date[3]
```

Потом `headers` используется в других файлах. У меня в чем проблема, значение этих переменных берется из БД, чтобы получить значение из БД, мне нужен user_id, в файле bot.py я получаю данные. Поэтому, передаю в файл Setting.py, но headers у меня не обновляет значения. Если я буду использовать в 1 файле, будут проблемы с импортом, один файл импортирует друг друга. Пробовал использовать глобальные переменные, классы, не помогло.

Как можно решить проблему?